# Redirect user when the worker is done

Tags: python, redirect, flask, worker

I have the app in python, using flask and iron worker. I'm looking to implement the following scenario:

1. User presses the button on the site
2. The task is queued for the worker
3. Worker processes the task
4. Worker finishes the task, notifies my app
5. My app redirects the user to the new endpoint

I'm currently stuck in the middle of point 5, I have the worker successfully finishing the job and sending a POST request to the specific endpoint in my app. Now, I'd like to somehow identify which user invoked the task and redirect that user to the new endpoint in my application. How can I achieve this? I can pass all kind of data in the worker payload and then return it with the POST, the question is how do I invoke the redirect for the specific user visiting my page?

Comment: wouldn't return redirect(url_for('endpoint')) work ?

Comment: Probably, but the question is when to call this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

- When the user presses the button the server starts the task, and then sends a response to the client, possibly a "please wait..." type page. Along with the response the server must include a task id that references the task accessible to Javascript.
- The client uses the task id to poll the server regarding task completion status through ajax. Let's say this is route `/status/<taskid>`. This route returns `true` or `false` as JSON. It can also return a completion percentage that you can use to render a progress bar widget.
- When the server reports that the task is complete the client can issue the redirect to the completion page. If the client needs to be told what is the URL to redirect to, then the status route can include it in the JSON response.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This will work, however I was wondering if it's possible to avoid polling in this scenario. Imagine 20k clients polling the back-end, this could have a significant influence on the performance.

Comment: If you want to support 20K clients then you have a bigger problem, you need enough CPU power to run 20K background tasks! In any case, the HTTP protocol does not allow the server to call the client, so it is not possible to have the server tell the client to redirect. If you go out of HTTP then you can do it. Check out web sockets, for example, where there is a bi-directional permanent connection between client and server.

Comment: Thanks Miguel, I think what you suggest is the proper way of doing what I want. However for a quick result I decided to use iron_mq queues which allow me to pass the messages between the worker and the client. The polling is still necessary but I don't see the way around it unless I go for web sockets which I'm not interested in at the moment.